# Perl script to fetch mail folders, for use with mbsync or offlineimap

Tags: gnus, email, mu4e, wanderlust, perl

I have been looking at various email setups using different tools within Emacs for the last few months. I looked at various email setups using Gnus, mew, mu4e, wanderlust etc.

While reading one of the setups on some blog, I was trying to setup `offlineimap/mbsync`. And it requires the name of folders to fetch. On one such blog there was a Perl script to fetch all these folder names automatically. and output them to a file. These folder names can then be used with other configuration scripts to specify which particular folders to fetch.

Now I have finally got a setup which I am staying with and it is working for me. It uses `mbsync + mu4e` . I have a lot of folders in my mail box as I used to use filters. I was only able to use INBOX and Sent Mails in that configuration, as other folders are a lot. And now I am again looking to find that Perl script.

Does any of you have came across such setup which uses some Perl magic to fetch folders for the configuration?

Comment: Finally found the page where the script was present. It was present on this blog explaining the setup of wanderlust for email with Emacs. http://mihai.bazon.net/articles/emacs/wanderlust-email-client

Comment: Direct link to the script http://mihai.bazon.net/articles/emacs/wanderlust-email-client/configure-email-folders/gen-folders.pl

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `Net::IMAP::Simple` perl module/package.
Below please find "version zero" based on the man page.

```pl
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Net::IMAP::Simple;

# Create the object
my $imap = Net::IMAP::Simple->new('imap.example.com', use_ssl => 1) ||
    die "Unable to connect to IMAP: $Net::IMAP::Simple::errstr\n";

# Log on
if(!$imap->login('user','pass')){
    print STDERR "Login failed: " . $imap->errstr . "\n";
    exit(64);
}

# List folders
my @folders   = $imap->mailboxes_subscribed;
foreach my $folder (@folders) {
   print $folder,"\n";
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, this works.

Answer (score 0):

Perl?  Seriously?

```
#!/usr/bin/emacs --script

(require 'imap)

(defun imap-get-subscribed-folders (server port user pass)
  (let ((buffer (imap-open server port)))
    (unwind-protect
         (with-current-buffer buffer
           (imap-authenticate user pass)
           (imap-mailbox-lsub))
      (imap-close buffer))))

(mapc #'(lambda (f) (princ f) (terpri))
      (imap-get-subscribed-folders "imap.example.com" nil "user" "password"))
```